# how to list grub2 menuentry in UEFI

Tags: grub2, uefi

I want to get the grub2 menuentry list of linux (centos 8 / fedora 32) with **UEFI** boot，to use `grub2-set-default`.

I can get menu list with this command in non uefi enviroment

```
awk -F\' '$1=="menuentry " {print i++ " : " $2}' /etc/grub2.cfg
```

I know that the grub.cfg is in a different path with uefi:

```
#non uefi cfg
/etc/grub2.cfg -> /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
#uefi cfg
/etc/grub2-efi.cfg  -> ../boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg
```

But if I can't get all the menuentry in  `/etc/grub2-efi.cfg`  like non uefi environment.

```
[root@vm-centos centos]# grep ^menuentry /etc/grub2-efi.cfg
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
```

What shall I do?

Answer (score 4):

In RHEL/CentOS 8, GRUB uses the new `blscfg` module, which reads the entries for individual Linux kernels from `/boot/loader/entries/`. There should be one `.conf` file per entry.

For more info, see  https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/BootLoaderSpecByDefault

This is not about UEFI, but is used by classic MBR-based GRUB too. In fact, the `/boot/loader/entries/` directory with its files will also exist on architectures that won't use GRUB at all, like s390x or aarch64.

Instead of numbers, the boot entries are identified by names, which are essentially the names of the individual `/boot/loader/entries/*.conf` files without the path and the `.conf` suffix.

The following might be a close equivalent of your `awk` one-liner for RHEL/Centos 8:

```
for i in /boot/loader/entries/*.conf
do 
    entryname=$(basename $i .conf)
    entrytitle=$(grep title $i | cut -f 2-)
    echo "$entryname : $entrytitle"
done
```

The default entry is identified by the `saved_entry=` setting in `/boot/grub2/grubenv` (in legacy BIOS/MBR systems) or `/boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grubenv` (in UEFI systems). In a default installations, both files will exist with identical contents in both BIOS/MBR and UEFI-bootable systems, but only one of them will get modified by GRUB if a non-default entry is chosen at boot time.

This snippet might be used to identify the currently-selected boot entry:

```
if [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ]
then
    envfile=/boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grubenv
else
    envfile=/boot/grub2/grubenv
fi
bootdefault=$(awk -F '=' '/^saved_entry/{print $2;}' $envfile)
echo "Default boot entry name: $bootdefault"
```

Comment: thanks ,this helps a lot. by the way  `grub2-editenv list` can also get the default entry